# NiFi - Distributed Tracing capability

Tags: apache-nifi, zipkin

We have integrated NiFi within our product suits. We would like to track a user request by "Trace Id", which spans across different components. Do let me know whether NiFi have some capability to support something similar to ZipKin.

Thanks

Senthil.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache NiFi's built-in provenance capabilities to trace how a given flow went through the system.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#data_provenance

Comment: Thanks Joe Witt for information.

But I'm looking for an end to end flow, where NiFi is part of it.  Finally we would like to have the logs aggregated to external system and trace the message with one trace id.

Do let us know, if the option available.